# How to disable !pip and %pip command in jupyter

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyterhub

Can we disable !pip and %pip commands in jupyter
I want to do this for i don't want to give package installation access to user in my machine learning product. Any one have an idea ?

Comment: Can you describe the environment and the purpose of letting anyone using you notebook ?
It seems like disabling pip won't do much (they can use os package for example)...

Comment: If you're going to be allowing arbitrary code execution, limiting the network and permissions of the container would be a stronger strategy. Consider `os.system("pip install ...")`. Also, consider copy+paste :)

Comment: This may be better answered on Jupyter discourse, but in either case more details are needed - what is your motivation (fear), what you want users to be able to do, etc. f you fear them executing arbitrary code on >your< machine, one solution would be to user jupyterlite which is running in users browsers, hence you no longer have that problem.